# Creating a Component that behaves like <ng-template> / whithout host-element in DOM

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular5

i want to to control a repeating path through a angular component. In my scenario the code is dynamicly generated and gets compiled in runtime. My problem is now that the host-element is showing in the DOM and may causing some unintended display issues. Is there a way to create a component that behaves like  or an other solution for this problem.

I created this Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/GV7xQOpkwdFmEJ9DQc5P?p=preview

```
### As i want to Use - but not working ###
<table style="width:400px; border:1px solid black">
<repeating-section *ngFor="let item of [true,false,true]; let i = index">
tr>
<td> {{ i +1 }}
<td> {{ item }} </td>
 </tr>
</repeating-section>
</table>

### Working Example - but now as wanted ###
<table style="width:400px; border:1px solid black; margin-top:30px">
<tr *ngFor="let item of [true,false,true]; let i = index">
<td> {{ i +1 }}
<td> {{ item }} </td>
</tr>
</table>

<ng-content></ng-content>
```

result:

[image]

best regards,

Comment: Have you tried `ng-container`, which will remove the extra `div`?

Comment: Maybe my example was to abstract. I need a component to implement my application logic and not using parent component for this.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed. I couldn't get it working. You might have to rely on directive instead of component, this way you can avoid adding extra element. However directive doesn't allow you to add template. To me it's complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer from a different direction.

Instead of using `table` tag, maybe we can try `display: table`, https://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero)

The reason I suggested this is that you don't want to have extra element wrapping `<tr>`, but if you can make any element a table, with some unified width control, you can use a component to wrap it up like you are doing.

Comment: This is not flexible. Guess the repeating section is in an ordered list or anything else

Comment: Actually if you rely on `div`, you shouldn't have this problem at all. `table` is special, you can't have any tag you want inside it. That is the reason I suggest `display: table`. What I really want you to do is to switching to `div`. This way you can control pretty much everything.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to influence this. My Code does not know what is before or after it's tag. It should handle all situtations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a Component with a tag-selector:

```
selector: 'repeating-section',
```

You can use an attribute-selector:

```
selector: '[repeating-section]',
```

and use it like so:

```
<tr repeating-section *ngFor="let item of [true,false,true]; let i = index">
    <td> {{ i +1 }}
    <td> {{ item }} </td>
</tr>
```

I hope I understood your problem correctly.